redireccion 301 no funcionan en servidor nginx
tengo un servidor de prueba en nginx y lo que quiero es redirigir tanto el http como el www a -> HTTPS non-www. ya intente separar los servidores dandome error
de redireccion en el puerto 443, tambien intente realizarlo desde htaccess pero nginx parece que no soporta ese tipo de archivos o aun no puedo configurar la instalacion y lo peor de todo es que sigue sin funcionar nose que puede estar fallado?
esta es la configuracion del sitio
server {

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        root /var/www/example/ecommerceapp/public;
        index index.html index.php;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # >
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; >
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}


hoy en día el primer probe se suele hacer al puerto 443 ( prefer https ) así que la redirección la tenes que meter en el bloque que escucha en ese puerto (listen 443). if ($host = www.example.com) { return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; } btw  cuando pones el condicional en el bloque que escucha en puerto 80, es conveniente también ya ponerle el scheme,  sino vas a encontrar que redirige primero a http://sinww y luego a https://sinwww ( para navegadores/requests/probes que arrancan por el puerto 80  )
